# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0.10'

Tags: python

Example:

```
test = int(input("Enter a number"))
test2 = test * 24
print(test2)
```

when i enter a float number like `0.10` i get this error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0.10'
```

`test = int(float(input("Enter a number")))` makes `0.10` to `0`

I want the output like this:

```
>>> 2.4
```

How do i fix?

Comment: You don't want an `int` at all, you want a `float`.  Just do `test = float(input("Enter a number"))`.

Comment: If you don't want an int then don't convert it to an int. Just do `float(input("Enter a number"))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

now it will work

```
test = float(input("Enter a number"))
test2 = test * 24
print("%.1f"%test2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a float as an input so use:

```
test = float(input("Enter a number"))
```